# How to set timing in icalendar without adding 1 hour for KSA timing

Tags: php, events, calendar, icalendar

I am using the ical to send email event to trainers when assigning them to courses and Trainers in Saudi Arabia. When sending email events to their emails added automatically 1 hour for timing and this is wrong with the timing i passed into the ical, please for your advise and help to set the time to ical as I passed to it.

This is the function I used:

```
function sendIcalEvent($from_name, $from_address, $to_name, $to_address, $BCC_to_address, $startTime, $endTime, $subject, $description, $location, $course_title, $loc_title)
    {
        $domain = 'testdomain.com';
        $mime_boundary = "----Training Booking----".MD5(TIME());
        $headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
        $headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";
        $headers .= "BCC: ".$BCC_to_address."\n";

        $message = "--$mime_boundary\r\n";
        $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
        $message .= "<html>\n";
        $message .= "<body>\n";
        $message .= '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
        $message .= "</body>\n";
        $message .= "</html>\n";
        $message .= "--$mime_boundary\r\n";

        $ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n" .
        'PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN' . "\r\n" .
        'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n" .
        'METHOD:REQUEST' . "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .
        'TZID:Arabia Standard Time' . "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
        'DTSTART:16011028T030000' . "\r\n" .
        'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETFROM:+0300' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETTO:+0200' . "\r\n" .
        'TZNAME:EST' . "\r\n" .
        'END:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
        'DTSTART:16010325T020000' . "\r\n" .
        'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETFROM:+0200' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETTO:+0300' . "\r\n" .
        'TZNAME:EDST' . "\r\n" .
        'END:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
        'END:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .  
        'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
        'ORGANIZER;CN="'.$from_name.'":MAILTO:'.$from_address. "\r\n" .
        'ATTENDEE;CN="'.$to_name.'";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:'.$to_address. "\r\n" .
        'LAST-MODIFIED:' . date("Ymd\TGis") . "\r\n" .
        'UID:'.date("Ymd\TGis", strtotime($startTime)).rand()."@".$domain."\r\n" .
        'DTSTAMP:'.date("Ymd\TGis"). "\r\n" .
        'DTSTART;TZID="Arabia Standard Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($startTime)). "\r\n" .
        'DTEND;TZID="Arabia Standard Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($endTime)). "\r\n" .
        'TRANSP:OPAQUE'. "\r\n" .
        'SEQUENCE:1'. "\r\n" .
        'SUMMARY:' . $course_title . "\r\n" .
        'LOCATION:' . $loc_title . "\r\n" .
        'CLASS:PUBLIC'. "\r\n" .
        'PRIORITY:5'. "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
        'TRIGGER:-PT15M' . "\r\n" .
        'ACTION:DISPLAY' . "\r\n" .
        'DESCRIPTION:Reminder' . "\r\n" .
        'END:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
        'END:VEVENT'. "\r\n" .
        'END:VCALENDAR'. "\r\n";

        $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="Training_Session.ics";method=REQUEST'."\n";
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
        $message .= $ical;

        $mailsent = mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers);

        return ($mailsent)?(true):(false);
    }
```

And used this called

```
$dtstart = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($session_details['start_date']));
$dtend = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($session_details['end_date']));

sendIcalEvent($from_name, $from_address, $to_name, $to_address, $BCC_to_address, $startTime, $endTime, $subject, $description, $location, $course_title, $loc_title)
```

## This image can explain the result

[click here to see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiEA5.png)

I expect the problem in iCal Time Zone issue. How to set it to (Saudi Arabia Riyadh)?

Answer (score 0):

The ics spec suggests using the Ohlson timezone db identifiers (same as php) See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-27.   It looks like the TZID you need is Asia/Riyadh. See http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-35
One can either issue your datetimes in UTC time and let the application convert to users timezone

```
DTSTART:19970714T173000Z                  ; UTC time
```

or with the TZID (and application convert from that to user's timezone in application)

```
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:19970714T133000                                        ; Local time and time zone reference.
```

the other option listed is 'local or floating time'. EG if event is 8am, then it is 8 am in all timezones.